# Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).(CRM 4.0, Visual Studio 2008 c#)

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm

Just wanted to thank you for taking your time to fix my problem, the objective down below is to eventual use the CrmService to get data from the CRM 4.0.

The application terminated with an error.

> Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
>   error CS0001: Internal Compiler Error (0xc00000fd)
>   error CS0003: Out of Memory

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    using Crm;
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try {
                CrmService Service = new CrmService();
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The application terminated with an error.");
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to exit.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

PS: This is a smaller version of the code just trying to test why `CrmService Service = new CrmService();` isn't working.

Webservice: 
Folder name: CRM 
URL Behavior: Dynamic 
Web Reference URL: http://[company ip]/MSCRMServices/2007/CrmServiceWsdl.aspx

Possible Reasons:

- I might not have permission, even though i can access their database with SQL Server;
- Missing libraries, references, web references.
- I'm running the program in win10 64bit, Visual Studio 2008

Any more ideas on ways i could try to solve this or eventually a solution are apreciated.

PS_2: I have already looked for several solutions in this regard trying to fix this problem, na example: ["Out of memory" exception on call to web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466089/out-of-memory-exception-on-call-to-web-service) 
Another issue might be that i'm on an intership so i'm a  bit limited in changes i can do on my own in regards to server etc.